# Column mapping in DataFrame write format JDBC in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I am able to load dataframe records into Oracle database without any errors but i wanted to know that how to column mapping in Df to Oracle

I wanted to map Employee_id field from DataFrame to ID column in oracle in JDBC write format.

column mapping :

```
df          ---------- Oracle
Employee_id ----------    ID


targetdf=spark.sql(final_sql)

targetdf.show()

targetdf.write \
   .format("jdbc") \
   .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@***************") \
   .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
   .option("dbtable", target_table) \
   .option("user", "hr") \
   .option("password", "******") \
   .mode('append').save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
targetdf = targetdf.withColumnRenamed("Employee_id", "ID")
```

before writing to the Oracle database. The mapping is based on column names.